# Centralizer of product Sylow subgroups intersection of centralizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, sylow-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a group (in my case $G$ is polycyclic but I don't know if it relevant). Let $A$ be the maximal abelian normal subgroup of $G$ and
$$A = \prod_i P_i$$
where $P_i$ are the Sylow subgroups of $A$. It is true that $C_G(A) = \bigcap_i C_G(P_i)$?

We know that $C_G(A) \subset \bigcap_i C_G(P_i)$. If $g \in \bigcap_i C_G(P_i)$ then $gh = hg$ for every $h \in P_i$ for all $i$. Since $A$ is the product of $P_i$, then $g \in C_G(A)$. But I don't know if this is correct.

If this is false, are there some hypotheses that makes it true?

Comment: where does the product live?

Comment: For any group $G$ and subgroups $H$ and $K$, we have $C_G(H)\cap C_G(K) = C_G(\langle H,K\rangle)$. Since the $P_i$ generate $A$, your equality follows. The statement follows because if $x$ is expressed as a product (of arbitrary length) and $y$ commutes with each factor, then it commutes with $x$. The other inclusion follows because if $B\subseteq D$, then $C_G(D)\subseteq C_G(B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We know that $C_G(A) \subset \bigcap_i C_G(P_i)$.

Yes, this true:
each $P_i$ is contained in $A$, whence $C_G(A)$ is contained in each $C_G(P_i)$.

> If $g \in \bigcap_i C_G(P_i)$, then $gh = hg$ for every $h \in P_i$ for all $i$. Since $A$ is the product of $P_i$, then $g \in C_G(A)$. But I don’t know if this is correct.

This is correct:
we can write every element $a ∈ A$ as a product $a = p_1 \dotsm p_n$ where each $p_j$ is contained in some $P_{i(j)}$.
We thus have
\begin{align*}
  g a
  &= g p_1 p_2 \dotsm p_{n - 1} p_n \\
  &= p_1 g p_2 \dotsm p_{n - 1} p_n \\
  &\enspace\vdots \\
  &= p_1 p_2 \dotsm p_{n - 1} g p_n \\
  &= p_1 p_2 \dotsm p_{n - 1} p_n g \\
  &= a g \,.
\end{align*}